# Permission problems in Location

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

```
package com.example.khatrimann.map_activity;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE_2 = 102;
//private   String  TAG = “MapDemo” ;
private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;

protected void requestPermission(String permissionType, int
        requestCode) {
    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            permissionType);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{permissionType}, requestCode
        );
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length == 0
                    || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to show loaction permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    /*// Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/


    if (mMap != null) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        }
        else {
            requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

I have added proper permissions in the manifest file, checked the run time permissions, everything is working except **mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)**.

When the activity is launched then it force stops, no error is sown in studio.

When the activity is launched for the first time (By studio) it gives toast "Unable to show location permissions" as written in code
When the activity is launched for second time (manually) it force stops and following error comes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.khatrimann.map_activity, PID: 17785
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GoogleApiClient parameter is required.
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.zzj(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzarl.getLastLocation(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.example.khatrimann.map_activity.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:95)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                                                                                     at zu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                                                                                     at maps.ad.t$5.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: If it crashes, there will be a stack trace.  Please include it in your question.

Comment: Post your stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must ask for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, if using `GoogleMap`, also try to optimize your code.

Your full edited code:

```
package com.example.khatrimann.map_activity;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE_2 = 102;
//private   String  TAG = “MapDemo” ;
private GoogleMap mMap;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;

protected void requestPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: 
            if (grantResults.length == 0
                    || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

//@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    /*// Add a marker in Sydney, Australia, and move the camera.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/


    if (mMap != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&  &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            //mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            // fetch location lat lng

        }
        else {
            requestPermission();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It is displaying toast "Unable to show location permissions"

Comment: That means u denied the permission. Grant the permission and check.

Comment: It is only displaying message once, and that is accepted

Comment: So, what is ur concern now, is it working as u wanted or what ? :)

Comment: Sir, it should ask for permission 2 times but it is asking only for the one time, after accepting it shows toast "Unable to show location permissions". Also when the activity is launched second time from android device drawer, it force stops.

Comment: it will ask only 1

Comment: but than why it is saying "unable to show location permissions"

Comment: working!! but when I start activity Failed looking up window
                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e86a78d does not exist

Comment: Is it fetching the location, and is the error causing app crash?

Comment: in else block when location code is added below requestPermission() it takes time to respond and force closes

Comment: what error u getting from logcat ? and dont add location code in else block add in `if` only bcoz permission is granted in if only

Answer (score 0):

> Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to
>   apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This
>   approach streamlines the app install process since the user does not
>   need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also
>   gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example,
>   a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not
>   to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any
>   time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp" >
  ...
  <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

...

Add this code to your activity in OnCreate

```
askForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,LOCATION);
///call this method

 private void askForPermission(String permission, Integer requestCode) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, permission)) {

                //This is called if user has denied the permission before
                //In this case I am just asking the permission again
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);

            } else {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + permission + " is already granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```